# How to make an element visible/overflow inside an element with overflow:hidden and position:relative

Tags: html, css

Given a container element with overflow:hidden, making a child element position:absolute normally makes the child pop out so it can be visible outside its container.

However, if the container has position:relative, this does not seem to work.

How do we get the child element to pop outside and still have position stuck to its parent when scrolling the page?
[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oow14fvf/6/)

CSS

```
/* Positioning */
#box1 { overflow: hidden ;position:relative}/*don't touch*/
#box2 { position: static ;}
#box3 { position: relative;}
#box4 { position: absolute;}/*make this show on top of everything*/
/* Styling */
#box1 { background: red; padding: 5px; width: 125px;height:30px }/*don't touch*/
#box2 { background: green; padding: 5px; width: 115px }
#box3 { background: blue; padding: 5px; width: 105px; height: 100px }
#box4 { background: yellow; padding: 5px; width: 95px; height: 150px }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="box1">
    <div id="box2">
            <div id="box3">
                <div id="box4"/>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This has been asked loads of times before. You have the option to move the 'yellow box' outside of its container, and position it absolutely if you want to 'show it fully'. (As you've said in your question)

Comment: `position: fixed;` :P

Comment: Please show me, the clue is tha box1 that has position relative makes this not work. (see fiddle). If I misunderstand, please link me an answer or fix the fiddle to show me what you mean.

Comment: position:fixed makes it pop out, but scrolling the page makes it position not scroll with the page :/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oow14fvf/4/

Comment: Like mentioned, most pages have scroll :/ http://jsfiddle.net/oow14fvf/5/

Comment: I'm aware that the original question is sortof solved, however my original problem needs the div to stick to its parent.